# I am beginner in NodeJS I make a http delete request but it not working

Tags: node.js, express

delete function code

```
deleteScreen:(screenId)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        db.get().collection(collection.SCREEN_COLLECTION).removeOne({_id:ObjectID(screenId)}).then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
            resolve(response)
        })
    })
}
```

http delete route is

```
router.delete('/delete-screen/:id',services.deleteScreen)
```

html code is

```
<a href="/theater/delete-screen/{{this._id}}" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete {{screen.ScreenName}} ?')">Delete</a>
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: i got not found error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your router handler actually receives `request` and `request` and `next`, so when you write.

```
router.delete('/delete-screen/:id',services.deleteScreen)
```

It means that the function `services.deleteScreen` will be called in the following way `services.deleteScreen(req, res, next)`; So you need to change the signature of your function.

```
router.delete('/delete-screen/:id', (req, res) => {
    services.deleteScreen(req.params.id)
         .then(() => res.end())
         .catch((e) => {
              res.status = 500; // means internal error;
              res.end();
         });
})
```

Comment: my service.deleteScreen is:                                                                                                                                                            exports.deleteScreen=(req,res)=>{
  console.log('deleted')
  let proId=req.params.id
      console.log(proId)
      theaterHelpers.deleteScreen(proId).then((response)=>{
        res.redirect('/theater/screens')
      })
}

Comment: when i replace router.delete to router.get it works but i want to make rest api how can i

Comment: Well, I suppose that you are making the call wrong. If you are using the browser to perform the request, the truth is that it always makes the `GET` calls whereas you expect `DELETE` calls. You can use Insomnia or Postman to test `DELETE` HTTP calls or any other HTTP calls.

Comment: i getiing not found error when delete button pressed

Comment: Make sure that you are using the same URL and Method defined in the server and in the application you are using.

Comment: actually it works on gets call i replace get call to delete to make rest api so i got this error not found on browser and my delete function is also not working

Comment: i think something is needed to make router.delete rest api i dont how it done

Comment: don't use delete URL direct from <a href /> tag, it'll make GET request by default,
Solution, make one function that called onclick of your delete button, and in that function specify your request method or type as `delete` and use it.